# 3 black, 3 red, no earth, spur, help

Tags: wiring, socket

I'm in the UK, very old flat, I want to add an SFCU spur (to be on the safe side) for an electric oven. I have two practical questions regarding the double socket wiring in the picture.

1. How come there is one pair of black & red coming from one conduit and two pair of black & red from the other?

First off, I don't see any nearby spur so shouldn't there be just two blacks and two reds (and two bares)? So where is the earth? The green seems to be just a short wire to the case.

2. I hope my nightmare won't come true and you don't tell me I must not spur off this socket. Then given we work out the connections, how would I stuff a fourth cable under a single screw, i mean I can try but isn't that a really bad practice? Would buying a modern socket make it easier?

[image]

Comment: if that is metal conduit, a connection to the conduit suffices for an earth connection.

Comment: Aa yes, it is metal :-) now makes sense! So i suppose once I get a T&E cable, I'll just connect the earth to the case as it also looks to be attached to both conduits by some kind of nuts or simply in good contact

Comment: I'm a bit worried about it being described as an oven, it might need its own circuit - I'm not familiar with UK wiring practices.

Comment: Well it sais only 2.1kw and even the kettle has 1850W up to 2200W and does not need its own circuit. I also read elsewhere people suggest to someone to just plug the oven in the socket. That's why I'm not quite worried.